# Python instances should be created at the beginning or create them as we need them?

Tags: python

If we talk about resources, memory, legibility what would be better between:

1. Create all the instances at the beginning of a method? (left side of the screenshot)
2. Create the instances as we need to use them? (right side of the screenshot)

Do you have any documentation that says which is better? I searched in the Python documentation but found nothing.

[image: screenshot of two code panes in VSCode]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: It is entirely a matter of personal preference.  Code is sometimes more attractive if the variables are created at the top, but many consider it good practice to delay the creation until you need them.  That way, the user does not have to remember how they were created -- it's right there.

Comment: It also depends on how expensive it is to create those objects. Does it take no time at all? You can think about creating them all in the beginning of the function. Does it take lots of time? Definitely create them just before you want them because you don't want to have to waste all that time waiting only to never use it.

Answer (score 1):

Well in python creating instances is creating instances, regardless of where you do such, the same amount of instances will be created taking the same amount of storage space.

If you're looking into memory conservation I'd recommend using the `del` operator when instances are no longer needed.

Other than that this is totally just up to personal preference, and how you'd like to format your code.